# Laguerre polynomials, how to compute the integral?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Laguerre Polynomials $L_n = L_n(x)$, $n=0,1,2$ satisfy the Laguerre differential equation,

$$xL''+(1-x)L' +nL=0\quad(3)$$

Show that the Laguerre differential equation $(3)$ can be written in the form

$$(x(e^{-x}\cdot L'))' +n(e^{-x}\cdot L)=0$$

I used the product rule to compute

$$L'(e^{-x}) + x((-e^x)\cdot L' + L''e^{-x}) + ne^{-x}\cdot L$$

which gives you equations $(3)$

However I cannot compute the next part.

For $n\neq m$, show that

$$\int_{0}^\infty L_nL_me^{-x}dx=0.$$

I apologise for not formatting as I really struggle with this.

Comment: @James Please verify that I did not change the intent to your question with my edits.

Comment: @Peter the question is the same, thank you

Comment: @Peter I only made small adjustments to your edit, so your question to op still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n\neq m$ and $I=\int_0^\infty L_n L_m e^{-x} dx$.

Observe firstly that $me^{-x}L_m=-(xe^{-x}L_m')'$ and $d(-xe^{-x}L_m')=(-xe^{-x}L_m')'dx=me^{-x}L_m dx$ (similarly for $n$).

By partial integration, we have: 
$$mI=\int_0^\infty L_n m L_m e^{-x} dx=\int_0^\infty L_n d(-xe^{-x}L_m')\stackrel{u=L_n, dv=d(-xe^{-x}L_m')}=-xe^{-x}L_m'L_n|_0^\infty +\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}L'_mL'_n dx=0+\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}L'_n dL_m\stackrel{u=xe^{-x}L'_n, dv=d(L_m)}=xe^{-x}L'_nL_m|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty L_m(xe^{-x}L'_n)'dx=0-\int_0^\infty L_m (-ne^{-x}L_n)dx=nI$$
Since $m\neq n$, we have $I=0$.

Comment: @snulty I don't need to know that. Observe $(xe^{-x}L'_m(x)L_n(x))|_{x=0}=0\times something=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x}L'_m(x)L_n(x)=0$ since we have that the limit of (polynomial/e^x) is 0 when x tends to infinity.